# Continuity of Functions with Sets Equipped with Subspace Topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $A, B$ be closed subsets with the subspace topology in the topological space $X = A \cup B$. Let $g:A \to Y$ and $h:B \to Y$ be continuous. Prove that if $g(x) = h(x)$ for all $x \in A \cap B$, then the function $f:X \to Y, \ f(x):= g(x)$ if $x \in A$ and $f(x):= h(x)$ if $x\in B$, is continuous.

**Below is a line of reasoning I'd like some help with. Is it good? Should I move in a different direction?**

I define the function as:

$$
   f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       g(x): A \to Y \ \forall x \in A \\
       h(x): B \to Y \ \forall x \in B \\
       h(x)= g(x)    \ \forall x \in A \cap B
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$

It seems reasonable to call $f(x)$ $f(A \cup B)$ so that if $x \in A$ then $f(A\cup B)=g(x)$, if $x \in B$ then $f(A \cup B) = h(x)$ and if $ x \in (A \cap B)$ then $f(A \cup B) = h(x) = g(x)$.

The continuity of $f(A \cup B)$ needs to be proven.

I will use the fact that $f$ is continuous if and only if every preimage of a closed set is closed.

$A \ \& \ B$ are closed  so $A \cup B$ is closed.

It remains to show that $f^{-1}(A \cup B)$ is closed.

First I show that $f^{-1}(A), f^{-1}(B)$ are each closed and therefore there union is.

Then I show $f^{-1}(A \cup B) = f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$.

This completes the proof.

**Thank you for taking a look!**

Comment: It doesn't make sense to label $f(x)$ and $f(A \cup B)$ as the same objects.  One is the image of a point in $A \cup B$ and the other is the image of the whole set $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is not quite right.  Using the definition of $f:X \to Y$ as given above is right, but what you need to show is that the preimage of any closed set in $Y$ is closed in $X = A \cup B$.  Observe that if $E \subseteq Y$ is closed then

$$
f^{-1}(E) \;\; =\;\; \{x\in X \; | \; f(x) \in E\} \;\; =\;\; \{x \in X \; | \; g(x) \in E, \; or\; h(x) \in E\} \;\; =\;\;  g^{-1}(E) \cup h^{-1}(E)
$$

where we note that since $g$ and $h$ agree on $A \cap B$.  Observe that this is the union of two closed sets so must be closed in $X$.

One other comment is to just be careful when you write the preimage of sets.  You wrote $f^{-1}(A \cup B)$ above but this doesn't make sense since neither $A$ nor $B$ are subsets of $Y$.

Comment: Thank you - that was helpful!